# Bad SQL grammar exception during Hybris Initialization

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sap-commerce-cloud, mysql-error-1064, hybris-data-hub

I am getting exceptions while trying to initialize the `Hybris` System.

> [java] ERROR 2020-09-26 01:24:20,025 [main] [DefaultDbScriptsExecutor] problem executing sql [reason: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [ CREATE INDEX addressIdx_12 ON addresses (p_email, p_country, p_postalcode, p_duplicate, TypePkString, OwnerPkString, p_original, createdTS, p_phone1, p_lastname)]; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes]

Can somebody help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your db has limit for key length as 3072. My knowledge there is no way to increase it for InnoDB.

If your columns collations are correct you need to remove some columns from this index.

Answer (score 0):

MySql index key length of 3072 bytes so it's better to create more than one index with a combination of your choice attribute then it should work.